# Xcode status: "Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS"

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I´m developing an Ionic application and add the iOS platform but when I try to compile with Xcode I have the following:

```
Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target "Dispositivos" and build configuration "Debug" is correct and that the file exists on disk.
```

[image]

I have already tried other applications that Ive created and I have no problem to compile them, only with this I get this error.
I´ve searched for solutions on the internet but I cannot solve my problem. Does anyone know why this appears? and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

check follow this
`Build Setting \ Signing \ Code Signing Entitlements`

This path of it must correct with the path of file `*.entitlements` in your ios project folder. Good luck